# Forward recovery time - Which diodes are the fastest?

Tags: diodes, flyback

I am trying to design an RCD clamp of a flyback. In order to limit the overshoot attributed to the time the diode takes to conduct, I need a fast diode. (That information comes from *Switching-Mode Power Supplies - Spice Simulations and Practical Design* written by the legendary Christophe Basso).

So, what is the fastest diode? Is a Schottky diode faster to conduct than a PN diode? Datasheet gives the trr but there is not always information about tfr and it is difficult to get an idea as it is difficult to compare equivalent packages.

Comment: Schottky is generally less suitable for snubbers because of the high capacitance and low peak ratings.  But it depends.  Most PN diodes have low enough forward recovery you won't notice, but there are also conditions where even well-performing types may fail.  In short: what do you need it to do?

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you for your answer. I have no needs. I was just wondering if Schottky diode could be better than PN diodes for a RCD clamp. (I already saw Schottky Diode in a RCD clamp)

Answer (score 4):

For a \$RCD\$ clamp, an ultra-fast diode is actually the best to limit the overshoot. Since you need 600-V types for a universal-mains flyback application, a MUR160 is a good fit but a slightly slower diode like the 1N4937 or the UF4007 can also do the job.

It is less known that the turn-on mechanism of a slower diode like the the 1N4007 (also called the forward transit time) is actually quite fast. As detailed in my [APEC 2011](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202011.pdf) seminar The Dark Side of the Flyback Converter, such diode can be successfully used in low-power converters, up to 15-20 watts I would say:

[image]

The overshoot linked to this diode at turn-on is 37 V versus 14 V with a MUR160 in a similar configuration so you obviously need more margin with the 4007. However, as this diode features a lossy recovery - it is a slow diode meant for rectification purposes - it naturally damps the spurious oscillations taking place when the diode spontaneously blocks. As such, the radiated EMI signature is improved as illustrated by the clean waveform in the picture. This has proven to be a useful characteristic for many designers.

Finally, to further deplete the leakage inductance at turn-off and thus reduce the stress on the \$RCD\$ clamp, it is a good practice to add a small 47-120-pF/1 kV across the drain-source of the MOSFET: this will delay the \$v_{DS}\$ rise and reduce turn-off losses but it will also slightly deplete the leakage inductance, effectively reducing the dissipated power in the clamp (see slide 43 of the PPT). Of course, it also affects turn-on losses in lack of ZVS so to be used parsimoniously.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Your book is so helpful to me. Sometimes I thanks god for being born after you :D I have already seen RCD clamp with a Schottky so I was wondering if a Schottky could have an interest in a RCD clamp ? And so the question of diode speed.